# Read docx file from VM and write it down to a stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I have a .docx file located on my virtual machine desktop which I want to write down to a stream.
So far this is what I have tried

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
string path = @"\\officeblrhome.somedomain\UserData$\username\Desktop\filename.docx";
var memoryStr = new MemoryStream();
memoryStr.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytytes(path), 0 , buffer.Length);
using (WordprocessingDocumenet doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStr, true)
```

And I get the an error that the file contains corrupted data. Is it possible that my path is wrong? If it is how to get the valid path from the VM? The word file itself is not corrupted.

Comment: There's nothing related to VMs in this question. There *is* a *highly dubious* attempt to read a remote file through an administrative share instead of a proper shared folder. Use `File.Open(path))` to open a FileStream instead of all this code. You need nothing more than `using var stream=File.Open(path);using var doc=WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream,true);`

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes to the code and seems that it's working

```
byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytytes(path); 
stream.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Only by accident - you don't need to explicitly store the bytes in a separate variable, but you do need to reset the position. The original code is wrong to begin with - use a FileStream directly instead of first loading the contents in memory

Comment: You won't find code that loads a byte buffer and then writes it to a MemoryStream either.  The current code creates two copies of the document, one in the variable and one in the memory stream. What you'll see is code that first opens a stream with `File.Open` then copies the contents to the memory stream with eg `fileStream.CopyTo(memStream);`. This way the file contents are stored directly into `MemoryStream` without a temporary copy. You can do the same thing to copy from one file to another, although `File.Copy` is usually good enough

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm not a C# dev but by chance I had to make this thing work. By saying the code is wrong you refer to the extra variable and the wrong concept I used there. But generally speaking the content of the file is stored and then used which was my initial goal. I was totally aware that probably this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: You need to understand what you're doing, not throw random code. In any language.`File.Open(path)` is enough to open a file stream. Why not use that?

Comment: Now that I know I would use it.